# How to handle URL with parameters in a SAP AJAX Webapp?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm writing a Wordpress/AJAX based SAP web application, and I have a question about URL handling.

My application (roughly) looks like this:

1. There is an `index.php` file which basically contains a page container and the client-side code to handle ajax calls.
2. The client-side code is responsible for switching the pages according to user clicks. It does that by calling the registered action, which is mapped to a server-side function that returns the html for that page. (So there is a function named `get_about_page()` that prints/returns the **HTML** of the requested page)

The problem with this setup is handling URLs.
The question at hand is **how do I handle requests to URLs like `http://domain.com/about`, for example?**

Had I had an `about.php` page, I could add a rewrite rule to direct all requests there.
I could also, theoretically, parse the URL on the client-side, and decide which ajax call to fire, but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: usually for this kind of setup you'd simply have all routes go to /index.php. however, if you're pullling in and replacing the whole page with ajax, you're not benefiting much from using ajax and instead are simply complicating things.

Comment: @KevinB thanks for commenting! could you elaborate please? how'd you otherwise do it? I'm replacing only a specific page container, while the rest is static and doesn't need changing.

Comment: that would be too much work for me to feel comfortable providing here on SO.

Comment: @KevinB I understand. Could you perhaps throw my a keyword or something I could use to research it and learn it myself?

Comment: Have you tried using Apache's `fallbackresource` directive and mapping all requests to `index.php`?

Comment: what's the problem with just reading the url and making the appropriate ajax call. Also reroute everything to index.php

Answer (score 2):

Use pre define wordpress api, it may help you